# How to search for all junction links in a given directories and its subdirectories

Tags: windows, search, junction

I'd like to able to find all junction links on a whole drive or just given directory. Is it e.g. possible with the Total Commander search plugins? I just can't seem to find any decent solution for this on Windows... I mean I do know that I can run this:

> dir /A:D /S

And I will get a list, but with far more then just junctions...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [SysInternals tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768):

```
junction -s .
```

Using only built-ins:

```
dir/ad/s . | findstr "<JUNCTION>"
```

Comment: Had to update junction, but it seems to work now (-q for c). Funny that dir+findstr seem to be as fast junction is. I though junction would be faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using only internal DIR command:

```
DIR /S /A:L > JunctionList.txt
```

This will produce nicely formatted file with all junctions in current directory and subdirectories, organized by folder.

Comment: That seems to work, but I actually like `junction -s .` format as I can easily parse it to have full paths of source an destination.

Comment: Unfortunately `dir /a:l` lists directory of type `<SYMLINKD>` as well as `<JUNCTION>`

Answer (score 3):

!!! **Beware** I noticed that it may miss entries occasionally. I have a lot links and that may confuse it. I didn't have the time to post a bug report to nirsoft so I have no further details to spare :/ !!!

A (much enhanced and UI enabled) alternative to junction is [NTFSLinksView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html) (freeware). The ability to

- have the results in a grid so I can sort them and
- select the ones I am interested at and
- keep only the interesting ones in a text file

is the answer to my questions :)

Comment: Nice tool, but doesn't work as fast as `DIR /S /A:L`.