# How to clean Windows\Installer folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, disk-space

My C:\Windows\Installer folder is huge: 14 GB. My understanding is that this is where failed updates go to die, and it should not be this big. What is the correct way to clean it on Windows 10?

Comment: The only safe method is to use the Cleanup Tool

Comment: The utility "Disk Cleanup" does not find these files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I free up drive space from the Windows installer folder without killing Windows 8.1?](http://superuser.com/questions/707767/how-can-i-free-up-drive-space-from-the-windows-installer-folder-without-killing), or [Is it safe to delete from C:\Windows\Installer?](http://superuser.com/questions/23479/is-it-safe-to-delete-from-c-windows-installer), etc.

Comment: have you tried the tool from my answer?

Comment: I disagree about this being the same question as "Is it safe to delete from C:\Windows\Installer?" because that question refers to Windows XP. WinXP solutions often do not work on Win8 & Win10.

Comment: I prefer the PowerShell version that you can see the source for - https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Delete-unused-msi-and-msp-aecf0bc8

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There is a relatively new tool called [PatchCleaner](http://www.homedev.com.au/Free/PatchCleaner) which detects and can delete old MSI/MSP files.

[image: PatchCleaner Screenshot]

From the PatchCleaner page:

> **Windows Installer Directory** When applications are installed and updated on the Windows Operating System a hidden directory
>   "c:\Windows\Installer" is used to store the installer (.msi) files and
>   the patch (.msp) files.
>
> Generally these files are important as during updating, patching or
>   uninstalling software it will use the .msi/.msp files. If you
>   blanketly delete all the files in this folder, you will find yourself
>   needing to rebuild windows.
>
> Over time as your computer is patched and patched again, these
>   installer files become outdated and orphaned. They are no longer
>   required, but they can take up many gigabytes of data.
>
> **PatchCleaner** PatchCleaner identifies these redundant/orphaned files and allows you to either:
>
> ***(Recommended) Move them to another location. If you want to play it
>   safe, just move them to another location, and you can always copy them
>   back. Delete them.***

First use the move option and wait a few days before you delete the moved files.

Comment: Excellent recommendation, I just used this tool myself. I feel a lot more better than running something else that says "delete everything in your Installer folder".

Comment: Well, I was wary about trying this -- but I am running Win10 on a 8yr old laptop, and my storage problem has gotten so bad that if it continues I will have to buy a new HD. So I bit the bullet. I ran the PatchCleaner (1.4.2.0) It did a quick scan and it told me it needed to keep 6 GB of files and could remove 12 GB. It allowed me to do nothing, or move the files, or delete them. It moved them to a different folder for me, and I am now copying them to external storage instead. I have restarted since running PatchCleaner; seems okay. Easy to use, seems to work, does not seem to break my PC.

Comment: Quick note: I downloaded 1.4.2.0 from CNET and it didn't work. Got the installer from Softpedia instead and that works.

Comment: @MarkRendle I always download the setup from the developer page and not from a 3rd party hoster

Comment: 20 gigs of files still in use, 6 gigs of files getting moved.  At least it's something

Comment: Does anyone know about a portable version? I've tried to just copy out the program files from the program directory, and start it up on another machine from a pendrive, but it crashed with "VBScript engine not found" error.

Comment: Ask this the developer of the tool

Comment: I am planning on making a portable version as I have had a few requests for this recently, but in the meantime if you prefer to run this from a usb drive, once installed you can just copy the installation folder c:\Program Files (x86)\HomeDev\PatchCleaner to your USB Key and it seems to run fine. Glad to hear it is working for people. Last few days some people (2) reporting issues with a recent MS silverlight patch, I am looking at this and a few minor changes for the next version. Cheers.

Comment: This worked well for me on a client PC with a seriously full HD. Moved 12GB with no ill effects. Thanks to the developer for making this, it was sorely needed.

Comment: @jcrawfor74 do you also plan to clean the folder **C:\ProgramData\Package Cache** where the MSI/MSP files are stored which are created with new WIX tools: http://wixtoolset.org/news/

Comment: Lol, I thought that it would work like Ccleaner. First a scan of files and note how much space you can win and then the actual action (removal). Appears to start removing stuff when you launch the application... Could have used a better warning.

Comment: As followup on my previous comment. It did **not** auto delete stuff on app launch! I could manually make a backup and saved almost 38gb of the original 44gb!! https://i.imgur.com/UXcGNwY.png

Comment: Wow.  I'd been struggling to maintain adequate space on my 128Gb surface pro 1 with the Windows folder taking up 72Gb.  PatchCleaner just clawed back 32Gb in unrequired patches.  That's not only amazing but means I don't have to find thousands of dollars to buy a new mobile development environment.  Awesome.

Comment: It is a shame what Microsoft is doing with the Installer directory! This solution even works on XenServer for Windows VM. On a virtualization platform it is sometimes not that trivial to raise the HDD space.

Comment: Thankfully the know-it-all mod jagoffs here didn't delete this question! It's literally the only helpful answer to this question I have *ever* found!

Comment: PatchCleaner has not been updated in several years and more recent reports indicate it is no longer as accurate as it once was at correctly identifying no-longer-required patches.