# The c-drive in Windows 10 is too large upto 140 GB. How to detect which is taking more storage space and how to reduce it?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, disk-space

I had recently upgraded to Windows 10 and noticed that the C-drive is almost up to 140GB of the whole 145GB drive. I have Visual Studio, Sql server, Netbeans and Android Studio. Other than these I don't even have Games running on my System and have not installed anything for quite a while. So, I understand that something is taking up too much space. How do I detect the source and safely remove it... A step by Step guide is much appreciated

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows

Comment: Run Disk Cleanup (as Administrator) `cleanmgr.exe` and see how much disk space it can free up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per John Keats answer, I first installed WinDirStat and found out the major problem was in the Installer folder. Then I followed this link
https://superuser.com/a/1050442/631619 and installed Patch Cleaner. It freed upto 30 GB of Memory for me.

But still there was an Unknown Folder which took upto 20GB. So then I installed TreeSize and ran the program as Administrator. The culprit I found was System Recovery folder. So I deleted my Restore points. Still there was no change.
Since I use a Dell Laptop, the Dell Backup and Recovery was taking up so much space and kept on increasing.

As I desperately needed to free up some space I entirely uninstalled Dell Backup and Recovery software. Along with it all 15GB of Back up Memory freed up(Not recommended to uninstall since this is not the proper way and may face consequences in the future.)

I still don't know if uninstalling Dell software as well as deleting Restore points was right or not.But I used it as a temporary fix. Will update the answer if I find a permanent fix.

P.S : Also do a disk cleanup to clear the files from Old Windows edition due up-gradation process (Mostly it gets deleted after some period of time after upgrading)

Answer (score 3):

Try TreeSize or WinDirStat. Also see disk cleanup in admin mode, there might still be system and installation files from your pre-upgrade state.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run: Disk Cleanup
2. Choose option to clean up "OLD System files"
3. Clean

Done!

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question "How do I detect the source"

Comment: have you tried what I told you to do? I guess no.

Comment: you can check each file once it gets populated by the system.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with the new Windows Settings app.

1. Press Windows key + I shortcut to open Settings.
2. Select system and then select storage from the left pane.
3. Finally tap or click on This PC (C drive) and it will show you everything. See the screenshot below.
   [image]

Tap or click on a category to see files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just ran out of HDD space to find out my APPDATA\Local folder is taking 262GB of my 500GB SSD.  I went through every single folder in APPDATA\local to find out which was taking so much space.

Divide all folders in half, highlight them, then properties to find out total size.  I picked the higher half, then divide it half, and repeat until I narrowed down the culprit.

In my case, two folders took nearly 250GB.  One of them was AppData\Local\Android folder which took 182GB all by itself.  After uninstalling Google Android SDK Tools and Studio, I deleted the folder.