# Can I copy C:/Windows/Installer folder from one machine into another?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installer, windows-10-v1607

Okay so I'm in a little bit of a pickle. I was trying something on my Windows folder yesterday `C:/Windows` and I kinda went ahead of myself a little and lost the Installer folder `C:/Windows/Installer` (for installing new system updates and what not). Yes, yes, irresponsible, should have backed up bla bla bla whatever.

My question is, is it okay to copy and replace this folder from another machine? The two machines both have Windows 10 version `1607`. The difference is that my original Installer folder was about 25GB while the "replacement" one is only about 3GB.

Comment: Well, you might be able to do something with the file set but I don't believe the file names of the cached MSIs will line up with those in your registry.  Also, the cached MSIs are for specific versions of the product installed.  If you're having an issue removing a particular product now, you might be able to search under: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\ for the product name. Check the LocalPackage path, then rename the MSI from the copied cache to match.  If you add the "Authors" and "Subject" columns to the Explorer Window it's quite easy to find which is which.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/joscon/2012/01/18/can-you-safely-delete-files-in-the-windirinstaller-directory/ and http://superuser.com/questions/707767/how-can-i-free-up-drive-space-from-the-windows-installer-folder-without-killing and http://www.pagestart.com/windowsinstallerfolder.html and on and on... we ain't stopping 'til 6 in the morning... watcha gonna do... Gotta pocket full of R***ers and my home boys do too

Comment: You can, but it won't solve the problem, you created by removing the folder.